# JTS (java topology suite) voronoi diagram

Tags: java, voronoi, jts

After implementing a very naïve tessellation for pictures I went looking for something faster since my implementation was taking some seconds for 4 digits sites, after looking around jts seemed right enough but I have been headbutting with it for a while now so I decided to come and ask here, I have a picture which I want to tessellate using a voronoi diagram, but once I setup the VoronoiDiagramBuilder with which seems (to me) the right parameters, many unexpected things happen.

```
VoronoiDiagramBuilder voronoi=new VoronoiDiagramBuilder();
    voronoi.setClipEnvelope(new Envelope(0,width,0,height));
    voronoi.setTolerance(0.01);
    voronoi.setSites(sitesList);
    Geometry geo=voronoi.getDiagram(new GeometryFactory());
    for(int i=0;i<geo.getNumGeometries();i++)
    {
        Polygon poly=(Polygon)geo.getGeometryN(i);
        zonesList.add(poly.getCoordinates());
    }
```

Where width=900, height=598, siteList=5000, which is the number of vertexes which the voronoi diagram will be built around.

I expect the Geometry area, geo.getArea(), to be 900*598, but it's actually a way greater number, same goes for geo.getPoints(), which returns a number that is greater that the siteList size; and at last the coordinates from the various polygons in the Diagram aren't within the envelope which I set with voronoi.setClipEnvelope(new Envelope(0,width,0,height)).

At this point I think I am getting something extremely wrong or maybe I should use another library to better suit my simple needs since jts seems way overkill for picture tessellation, even if I like the speed.

Comment: Your sitesList are coordinates or a geometry within 900x598? A Voronoi diagram has more points than the number of points you entered. Maybe you want triangulation instead of a Voronoi diagram? Try to visualise the results, it will help you understand what is happening. You can copy-paste WKT into OpenJUMP for example.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the Tektosyne library.

It can generate Voronoi diagrams and Delaunay triangulations for you ;)

https://github.com/kynosarges/tektosyne

Comment: I've also got this behaviour where JTS extends Voronoi cells beyond the clip-envelope. I have no idea why it does it.